# How to execute multi-line ssh command stored in a variable

Tags: bash-scripting

Context: I'm trying to execute a bunch of commands on a remote machine that I cannot access directly - I first have to ssh into a gateway machine, then ssh from there and run the commands.

Basically what I'm after is a way of packaging up a set of commands that I can pass through any number of levels of ssh.  Can this be done?  I suspect the best answer is going to be using scp to copy a script across, then run that, which is an option.

Note that I've used the hostname command as a way to show what's going on - that's not what I really want to do!

Starting from a command that does a single ssh, and runs a multi-line set of commands there:

```
ssh gateway.my.company "
  hostname;
  hostname;
"
```

This works fine.  The output is something like:

```
target_machine
target_machine
```

I then stored the set of commands in a variable, and passed that in:

```
command="
  hostname;
  hostname;
"
ssh gateway.my.company $command
```

The output of is exactly the same - both `hostname` commands get executed on the target.

Next, I add in the extra ssh hop (to the private machine):

```
ssh gateway.my.company ssh target_machine_ip $command
```

This time the two `hostname` commands are run on different machines:

```
target_machine
gateway_machine
```

It appears I can resolve this step by wrapping the cmd in escaped quotes (i.e. `\"$command\"`), but if I do so then I have to wrap it differently for the direct case as `ssh gateway.my.company \"$command\"` no longer works

NOTE: I appreciate that commands shouldn't be stored in a variable but in a function, but as I'm using ssh any function I declared wouldn't exist once I'd ssh'ed into the next server.

EDIT: Original question omitted the second hop, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

you're only missing some quotes:

```
ssh gateway.my.company "$command"
```